# Issues while changing ArcSDE from a Workgroup to Domain Environment

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, domains

Our organisation was a having a multi-user Geodatabase ( ArcSDE 10.1 gateway on an Oracle 11 g DB) in a Workgroup configuration.

The type of Authentication for DB connection was "Database authentification"

Now Our IT is moving ahead with a New Domain/Active directory based Server access - This means the existing workgroup users will be changed to Domain users.

Now I though the new users will be able to access the ArcSDE connection using same old Database Username and password.

But encountering an error :

> Failed to connect to specified server : ORA-12154 : TNS : could not
>   resolve the connect identifier specified.No extended error

What does it mean and what is the way forward, if we prefer not to disturb existing connections/usernames , but I want to change  to Domain?

Answer (score 1):

You want to create domain groups to assign the privileges to.
In your question you are mixing terminology. 
If you have sde application server installed? The only database supported is an enterprise.
Arcgis server can be workgroup, enterprise but that has nothing to do with the database.